# Log location of varnish

Tags: varnish, varnish-4

I have went through this [article](http://After%20going%20through%20this%20article%20I%20am%20having%20the%20following%20doubts.%20Can%20some%20one%20help%20me%20to%20clarify%20this:-). Can some one help me to clarify the following doubts about the various log locations of varnish?

1. As per the varnish ebook varnishncsa -displays Varnish access logs & varnishlog is used to access request-specific data. Can some let me know what logs then go in `/var/log/messages` & `/var/log/syslog` ?
2. When varnish crashes due to panic where will varnish dump the logs/traces? I know `panic.show` shows the panic messages in cli. Is there a way I can view the panic messages in some files?
3. When varnish crashes due to segfault where will varnish puts the messages and core dump?
4. How can I dump the 503 / *Guru Meditation* errors in a file?

I am having these doubts on varnish 4.1 in Debian based systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) /var/log/syslog and /var/log/messages are normally for syslogd. Varnish does not configure these; they should already be setup.

2) I have always viewed Varnish messages in syslog (/var/log/messages)

3) Core files are system specific. The first thing you need to do is enable core files on your system. You need to put "ulimit -c unlimited" in the varnish startup script. For an OS with init.d, edit the '/etc/rc.d/init.d/varnish' file and add the above line to the "start()" section.

As to where the core files are stored you can use something like:

echo '/tmp/core_%e.%p' | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern

You are also probably going to want to build varnish from the source and turn on debug flags so that your core files have a symbol table that you can look at.

Running 'ulimit -c unlimited' at the command line and restarting Varnish is not going to work.